# Combine substr_replace with str_replace in php

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is to replace a specific string with another only if found in a certain position.

php:

```
$substr = substr_replace($string, $replacement, $stringstart);
$str = str_replace($quoted, $replacement, $str);
```

I plan to replace $string with $replacement in the string $str but only after $stringstart characters.

I also have $stringend. If I could also use that(because I know exactly the length of $replacement), it would be great. This is optional though

Comment: Interesting. Any question/problem where we can help you? [ask]

Comment: Would be a lot more helpful if you could provide sample input and output.

Comment: I did read that. What is that you could not understand from my question? I am just starting with PHP and I have used these functions alone but never together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$strToSearch="There is no need searching here. The search need to start here";
echo str_replace("need to start","started",substr($strToSearch, 32, strlen($strToSearch)));
```

This will produce the result:

```
"The search started here"
```

Comment: so sorry. I forgot to mention. My $str is an array. I have it printed twice : $str[0] and $str[1]

Comment: That makes your question more complex. I dont understand how it fits into the question above. can you correct the Original question?

Comment: I have made the explode function after your function. it still does not work as intended. It is deleting EVERYTHING before, also including the $strtosearch.

Comment: I want to have $strtosearch wrapped into "div class="example">$strtosearch</div> . This is why I am making the replacement.

Comment: You have an $arr which you want to search for a particular string in it or you have a string and want to search your string? I am confused at what your need is

Comment: I have a string (let's name it $motherstring) that contains $child strings. I want to replace $child string with <div class="example">$child</div> only if $child is found after int()$number of characters.

Comment: Okay lets take it this way; you have a string say $motherString="I am child of my mother string. I am also part of mother string. Even I am part of our mother string"; $replacement="I will replace one the child string"; Dose this represent your case? If so use $motherString and $replacement to explain your case

Comment: $replacement will replace $child only if $child is located at $my_own_number  of characters from the start of $motherString

Comment: If this is your case, Then my first solution will do just that; $motherString="I am child of my mother string. I am also part of mother string. Even I am part of our mother string"; $childString="I am also part of mother string." $replacement="I will replace one the child string";  echo str_replace($childString,$replacement,substr($motherString, $my_own_number, strlen($motherString)));

Comment: yeah, but that is also ERASING everything before it from the mother string. I want to keep everything else intact. just wrap the child in a div

Comment: That is logically impossible, unless you are not doing it right. I have tested this sample as stated above and have re-echoed the at the end and still get the value it is originally.

Comment: Try this to confirm it, can copy and paste the code below.     $my_own_number=31;
        $motherString="I am child of my mother string. I am also part of mother string. Even I am part of our mother string"; 
        $childString="I am also part of mother string."; 
        $replacement="I will replace one the child string"; 
        echo str_replace($childString,$replacement,substr($motherString, $my_own_number, strlen($motherString)));
        echo $motherString;

Comment: your code replaces "I am child of my mother string". if the number is 31, I want to replace "I am also part of mother string."

skip that number of characters then do the replacing

Comment: $my_own_number=31; 
    $motherString="I am child of my mother string. I am also part of mother string. Even I am part of our mother string"; 
    $childString="I am also part of mother string."; 
    $replacement="I will replace one the child string"; 
    echo substr($motherString, 0, $my_own_number).str_replace($childString,$replacement,substr($motherString, $my_own_number, strlen($motherString)));

Comment: Yep. This solves everything. The only downside is that I have no "ending number" so it is replacing EVERYTHING after that 31.
Thank you so much for your interest! If you could also add an ending number (defined by me, of course. I have both - end and start), that would be fantastic!

Comment: Sure! there is a limit to what it will replace strlen($motherString) in the echo specifies the length. You can change it to any number to see the behavior